# Flutter error (type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, String>')

Tags: flutter, dart

when I try to decode the json it gives me error.

my model class

```
class States{
  String name;
  String abbreviation;
  States({this.name, this.abbreviation});

  factory States.fromJson(Map<String,String> json){
    return States(
      name: json['name'],
      abbreviation: json['abbreviation']
    );
  }
}
```

function where I'm using it

```
Future<void> search(String text) async {
    String jsonString = await loadData();
    var data = jsonDecode(jsonString);

    var states = States.fromJson(data);//here it gives me error

    if (textEditingController.text == null ||
        textEditingController.text.isEmpty) {
      streamController.add(null);
      return;
    } else {
      print(text);
      streamController.add(states.name.startsWith(text.toLowerCase()));
    }
  }
```

the json data

```
[
    {
        "name": "Alabama",
        "abbreviation": "AL"
    },
    {
        "name": "Alaska",
        "abbreviation": "AK"
    },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You're passing `List<Map>` where your parameter is `Map<String,dynamic>`.

```
[
    {
        "name": "Alabama",
        "abbreviation": "AL"
    },
    {
        "name": "Alaska",
        "abbreviation": "AK"
    },
]
```

Do this :

```
 List<State> states = data.forEach((value) {
   States.fromJson(value);
  });
```

This way you'll get a list of `States`, created using your `list` of response.

Comment: hello thanks for answering but then it gives error like this " type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, String>' "

Comment: @Pokaboom Updated my answer. Can you check now and let me know.

Comment: it does give me that error but when tried to use where clause on it then it says 'where' was called on null but when print the states it does give me the map this last thing if you can help me?

Comment: @Pokaboom Can you share the code on which you added `where`?

Comment: streamController.add(states.where((element) => element.name.startsWith(text)));   here text i'm getting from argument and sorry in my last comment it does **not** me that error

Comment: @Pokaboom I think you have another question, can you update your question with the same.